# Store a sql select statement, ran from VBA, in a numeric variable

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, vba

I'm working on creating a dynamic pass-through query and in order to do so I first need to query my local db and get an ID.
This ID is what I will put into my pass-through query for my WHERE clause of the query.

My string:

```
getCorpID = "SELECT corpID " & _
            "FROM dbo_corp " & _
            "WHERE name = " & Forms.frmMain.Combo4.Value
```

I'm then trying to do something akin to:

```
CorpID (integer) = docmd.runsql (getCorpID)
```

I realize, however that docmd runsql doesn't work with select statements, or return a value even. What can I use to run my string

```
getCorpId
```

as sql and store the result (It will only be one result, every time.. one number) in my variable CorpID

Thank you.

Comment: Note that constructing a query this way leaves you open to SQL injection.  If you're going to do database development, you should be familiar with this subject.

Comment: You can include quite a lot in a combo so why not just refer to a combo column?

Comment: Jon, I'm just an intern and not even in my senior year of undergrad. Just learning it all as I go.

Comment: @user3191081: No problem, everyone starts at the beginning.  Just please do cover that before releasing production code!  If you bring it up before your boss does, he or she may be impressed.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I ended up talking to a co-worker about the method I was attemptiong and he introduced me a bit to ADO, we made sure to close the connection at the end of the sub, I think this is what you were referring to. Thanks for the heads up, good to know people are trying to keep us amateurs from too many major mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider about using [Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx) :

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsSQL As DAO.Recordset
Dim getCorpID As String
Dim CorpID 

Set dbs = CurrentDb


getCorpID = "SELECT corpID " & _
        "FROM dbo_corp " & _
        "WHERE name = " & Forms.frmMain.Combo4.Value
Set rsSQL = dbs.OpenRecordset(getCorpID , dbOpenSnapshot)
rsSQL.MoveFirst
CorpID = rsSQL.Fields("corpID")
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely got me moving in the right direction.